# How to create scatter plot one after another removing previous in d3js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I have a .csv file having multiple columns of data.
x,y,d1,d2,d3
28,77,1,2,3
27,78,4,5,6
21,79,2,7,9
10,80,5,7,8

I am able to create a scatter plot of d1, d2 & d3 on a single graph but what is required is: first d1 is plotted then it is removed and d2 is plotted & so on.

I know this can be achieved using separate function & setTimeout() for each data set but I have many data sets like this, so writing same code multiple times is not efficient.

Can somebody help me out in this?

EDIT:
So this is a part of code modified according to what @Lars suggested and it is working as I wanted!

```
   var indices= d3.keys(mydata1[0])
            .filter(function(d) { return (d !== "xaxis" && d!="yaxis"); }).sort();
   indices.forEach(function(d, i) {
   setTimeout(function() { update(d); }, 5000 * i);
    });
   function update(idx) {

    p.selectAll("ellipse").remove(); //remove previous plot--to give animation like effect

    p.selectAll(".R")
    .attr("class", "ellipse")
    .data(mydata1)
    .enter()
    .append("ellipse")
    .attr("cx", function(d){ return scaleX(d["xaxis"]);})
    .attr("cy", function(d){return scaleY(d["yaxis"]);})
    .attr({
        "rx": 3,
        "ry": 4,
        })
    .attr("fill", function(d)
    {    
        d[idx]=(d[idx]/2)+32;
        for(i=0; i<64; i++)
        {
            if (d[idx]==0)
                return mycolor[0];
            else if(d[idx]>i && d[idx]<=(i+1))
                return mycolor[i];
            else if(d[idx]<0)
                return "none";
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically two ways of doing this. First, `setTimeout` to update the part of the data that is referenced. This would look something like the following, assuming `data` holds your data.

```
function update(idx) {
  svg.selectAll("circle")
     .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d[idx]); })
     .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d[idx]); });
}

var indices = ["d1", "d2", "d3"];
indices.forEach(function(d, i) {
  setTimeout(function() { update(d); }, 1000 * i);
});
```

Alternatively, you can use D3's `.transition()` to effect the same thing. This is a bit awkward as it wasn't intended for this kind of thing. The idea is to create a set of dummy elements to drive the transitions.

```
svg.selectAll("dummy").data(indices).enter().append("dummy")
   .transition().duration(1000).delay(function(d, i) { return i * 1000; })
   .attr("foo", function(d) { update(d); });
```

I would recommend going with the approach that uses `setTimeout`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I edited my ques and put the code according to your suggestion :D